# Android bold text in String-Array

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, arrays

I need to bold some text in a String Array, where each item is being used in a ViewPager. I am using `getTextArray()` to grab the formatted text from the xml file, and cannot cast that into a `String` to be able to be used in the ViewPager.

This is what I recently tried, but it stripped the formatting:

```
CharSequence[] arr = getResources().getTextArray(R.array.array);

String[] arrString = new String[arr.length];
int i=0;
for(CharSequence ch: arr){
    arrString[i++] = ch.toString(); 
}

for (String s : arrString) {
    mArrayList.add(s);

}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="array">
        <item><b>bold text</b>|<i>italic text</i></item>
        <item>Second Item</item>
        <item>Thrid Item</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

**ViewPager if relevant**

```
ViewPager mViewPager;
ArrayList<String> mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
MyAdapter mAdapter = new MyAdapter(context, mArrayList);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

I appreciate any advice, thanks

Comment: Why don't you make your adapter receive an `ArrayList<CharSequence>` instead of `ArrayList<String>`?

Comment: That worked. I tried it before but this time I was able to get everything else working correctly, thanks a lot! Not sure if there is a way to remove a question..

Comment: I'll write a short answer, and then you can accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String` objects cannot contain embedded markup (i.e. fonts, colors, styles). When you use this code:

```
for(CharSequence ch: arr){
    arrString[i++] = ch.toString(); 
}
```

you're losing the markup information that the resources contained.

You should simply change the `Adapter` to recieve an `ArrayList<CharSequence>` instead, and place those values directly into TextViews (or wherever the adapter is currently placing them).